# Swift 3 Connect to server with invalid certificate for XML

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, nsurlsession

I'm having some issues with a connection to a server. I want to simply send a username and password and get some data from an XML file.

```
    let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
    let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

    let baseUrl = "xxxxxx"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: baseUrl)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    var err: NSError?

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if data == nil {
            print("dataTaskWithRequest error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)
        print(xml["mobile_devices"]["mobile_device"]["serial_number"].element?.text)

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            // use main thread for UI updates
        })

    }
    task.resume()
```

When I run it, I get the following error(s):

> nw_coretls_callback_handshake_message_block_invoke_3 tls_handshake_continue: [-9812]
>   2017-05-04 08:20:45.311 xxxx[23410:4428038] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
>
> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
>   dataTaskWithRequest error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “xxxxxxx” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=("cert(0x7f88d8834000) s: xxxxxxx JSS Built-in Certificate Authority>",

I've never really done anything with APIs and things before, so I'm learning as I go. Previously I had to edit the plist file to allow the connection, and that fixed a problem I had before. I've got this far but I'm not sure how to get past it.

I saw this: [Connect to a Server with Invalid Certificate using NSURLSession (swift2,xcode7,ios9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128240/connect-to-a-server-with-invalid-certificate-using-nsurlsession-swift2-xcode7-i)
 but it broke the

```
let session = URLSession.shared
```

line in my code.

I've seen this as well, but I'm unsure how to use it:

[Swift: How to request a URL with a self-signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063927/swift-how-to-request-a-url-with-a-self-signed-certificate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found a solution for my own situation. I posted it here:  [Swift 3 NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed when connecting to a site with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847836/swift-3-nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-when-connecting-to-a-site)

Note: this is a security concern so please don't do this